# How to pass value to a dropdownlist in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist inside a gridview, my gridview has a datatable datasource and when i try to pass the value to the datasource, it doesnt handle the value.

```
 SqlCommand com2 = new SqlCommand("select MRPFABRIC.GoodForHow, MRPFABRIC.MrpQty, allowance, ArticleFabricAssign.Consumption,(select SUBDETAILS.Description from SUBDETAILS where SubDetailsID = MRPFABRIC.ColorName) as Color,(select SUBDETAILS.Description from SUBDETAILS where SubDetailsID = MRPFABRIC.FabricName) as Fabric from MRPFABRIC join ARTICLE on ARTICLE.ControlNo = MRPFABRIC.ControlNo join ARTICLEFABRICASSIGN on ARTICLEFABRICASSIGN.ArtFabID = MRPFABRIC.ArtFabId join FABRIC on FABRIC.FabricID = ARTICLEFABRICASSIGN.FabricID join mrp on MRP.MRPNo = MRPFABRIC.MRPNo where MRP.MRPNo =  @fmno and ARTICLE.ArticleNo = @articleno", con);
        com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fmno", txtMRPNo.Text);
        com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@articleno", ddlArtNo.SelectedItem.Text);
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(com2);
        adapt.Fill(dt2);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt2;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

and the passing of values is here

```
 DropDownList ddlfab = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("ddlConst");
                        DropDownList ddlcol = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("ddlColor");
                        TextBox txtgfhm = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox5");
                        TextBox txtconsump = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox6");
                        TextBox txtallow = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("TextBox7");
                        Label lblmrpq = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("Label1");

                        DataRow row2 = dt2.Rows[0];
                        ddlfab.SelectedItem.Text = dt2.Rows[i][5].ToString();
                        txtgfhm.Text = dt2.Rows[i][0].ToString();
                        txtconsump.Text = dt2.Rows[i][3].ToString();
                        txtallow.Text = dt2.Rows[i][2].ToString();
                        lblmrpq.Text = dt2.Rows[i][1].ToString();
                        ddlcol.Text = dt2.Rows[i][4].ToString();
```

the ddlcol is the one who doesnt handles the value.
i tried ddlcol.SelectedItem.Text but it returns null reference exception though the row i tried to pass has a value. ddlCol.SelectedValue also returns nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
        ddlcol.DataSource= dt2            
        ddlcol.DataTextField = "UserID";
        ddlcol.DataValueField = "UserID";
        ddlcol.DataBind();
```

you really need to check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.dropdownlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks, but it didn't work well too. it grabs the value but it didn't display it.

Comment: is ddlArtNo a dropdownlist ?

Comment: yes, it is a dropdown list outside the gridview, when the user choose on ddlArtNo, the ddlCol must change its value depends on the value of the ddlArtNo.

Comment: if so you need to
com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@articleno", ddlArtNo.SelectedItem.Value.ToString());

Comment: uhm i have no problem with the source, it works perfectly well, the main problem is that my ddlCol didnt print the value that was passed to it.

Comment: ddlcol.Text = dt2.Rows[i][4].ToString();
the ddlcol is the one who doesnt handles the value. i tried ddlcol.SelectedItem.Text but it returns null reference exception though the row i tried to pass has a value. ddlCol.SelectedValue also returns nothing.

Comment: use dropdownlist selectedindexchanged event when the user choose on ddlArtNo, and Check if listbox has property AutoPostBack="True".

Comment: try to use DropDownList ddlcol = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlColor"); to find the DropDownList

Comment: im sorry, i cannot use it because the trigger/sender is outside the gridview.

Comment: it's ok, i appreciate your help :)

Comment: ohh you can try last thing just add this code ddlcol.DataSource= dt2; before   ddlcol.DataTextField = "UserID";
         ddlcol.DataValueField = "UserID";
         ddlcol.DataBind();